# Testing second application from first application using robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I have an application which is tested using robotium. All the features of the application is tested properly. Finaly this application plays a particular content using media player. The media player is a second application. So while playing i am not able to return from the player using Solo.sendKey command(i think this is because the player is another application). Is there any way to communicate with the 2nd application from the 1st one using robotium ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't. Robotium can only test one app at a time.